# Can you show PHP within a Javascript alert box?

Tags: php

I have this code on a landing page that is a intro pop. It's supposed to display the visitor's carrier IP that is passed in as a URL token to a parameter. The intro pop works if I remove the inner PHP, but it doesn't work if I remove it. Did I code this alert box incorrectly with the inner php?

```
            <?php
                 echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Herzlichen Glückwunsch!\n\n" + <?php echo(isset($_GET["visitor_isp"]) ? $_GET["visitor_isp"] : ""); ?> + " Benutzer!\nSie wurden als Gewinner des heutigen KOSTENLOSEN iPhone 7, PlayStation 4 oder Samsung Galaxy S7 ausgewählt!\n\nBitte klicken Sie auf OK, um Ihren Preis in Anspruch zu nehmen, bevor wir es an jemand anderen verschenken!");
            </script>'
            ?>
```

Comment: Don't use php inside of php, google how to concat strings and you'll see. Once you have startet php with `<?php` there is no need for another set of those tags unless you have ended the php tag with `?>`

Comment: Can I use PHP inside of javascript?

Comment: @JamesHanford yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use PHP inside of Javascript, It will load up the values while the page loads, and the values remains same until page reloads.

You can use ajax if you wish to reload php values without page refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Herzlichen Glückwunsch!\n\n <?php echo(isset($_GET["visitor_isp"]) ? $_GET["visitor_isp"] : ""); ?>  Benutzer!\nSie wurden als Gewinner des heutigen KOSTENLOSEN iPhone 7, PlayStation 4 oder Samsung Galaxy S7 ausgewählt!\n\nBitte klicken Sie auf OK, um Ihren Preis in Anspruch zu nehmen, bevor wir es an jemand anderen verschenken!");
</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You were opening php tags inside php tags. You only need to concat the string and echo it once, as per example below.

```
<?php
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Herzlichen Glückwunsch!\n\n"' . 
                   (isset($_GET["visitor_isp"]) ? $_GET["visitor_isp"] : "").
                    ' Benutzer!\nSie wurden als Gewinner des heutigen KOSTENLOSEN iPhone 7, PlayStation 4 oder Samsung Galaxy S7 ausgewählt!\n\nBitte klicken Sie auf OK, um Ihren Preis in Anspruch zu nehmen, bevor wir es an jemand anderen verschenken!");
            </script>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use PHP inside of javascript?

yes you can ,but what you are doing is mixing php within php

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     <?php $visitorIsp = isset($_GET["visitor_isp"]) ? $_GET["visitor_isp"] : ''; ?>
     alert("Herzlichen Glückwunsch!\n\n" + <?php echo $visitorIsp; ?> + " Benutzer!\nSie wurden als Gewinner des heutigen KOSTENLOSEN iPhone 7, PlayStation 4 oder Samsung Galaxy S7 ausgewählt!\n\nBitte klicken Sie auf OK, um Ihren Preis in Anspruch zu nehmen, bevor wir es an jemand anderen verschenken!");
</script>
```